# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 while using Google-Maps-iOS-SDK (1.8.1)

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to add **Google-Maps-iOS-SDK (1.8.1) using cocoapods (0.33.1)**.

Deployment target version: **iOS 7.0**

I have added this pod: `pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'`, '~> 1.8'
Downloaded and installed sdk properly.

I started adding header file and sample map view loading code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start).

I have properly added API keys. In one view controller's `- (void)viewDidLoad`,
I have added following code:

```
 // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
// coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

I got this error on build for iPhone (not in simulator)

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DealDetailsViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DealDetailsViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DealDetailsViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I also tried using google map iOS sdk manual installation (without cocoapods). I have also added linker flag: `-ObjC`. It builds fine but crash on runtime showing selector not found error like this:

an NSException is thrown with the description -
-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I just need to use google map iOS SDK either using cocoapod or from manual installation.

Am I missing anything here?

**Edit**

If there is anything related with Pods.xcconfig then here is the content of that file:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK" "$(PODS_ROOT)/Parse-iOS-SDK"
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Bolts" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Facebook-iOS-SDK" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/MBProgressHUD" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Parse-iOS-SDK" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Reachability" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/WYPopoverController"

    OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Bolts" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Facebook-iOS-SDK" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDK" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Google-

    Maps-iOS-SDK" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/MBProgressHUD" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Parse-iOS-SDK" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Reachability" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/WYPopoverController"

    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework Parse -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social
    PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Comment: Check the included architecture slices just in case `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info XXX.a`

Comment: are there any warnings like "Ignoring file GoogleMaps.framework ....." ?

Comment: no there are not any warnings

Answer (score 50):

It's looks like the linker cannot find a sdk lib. Headers are present, but sdk objects-file not linked to a project.

Checking this:

BuildSettings->Linking->Other Linker Flags must have a value $(inherited)

[image: See image]

Comment: It does not work. I had already tried it. Is there is any specific with Xcode version then I am using Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow all the steps mentioned below ?

1. Launch Xcode and either open an existing project, or create a new
   project. If you're new to iOS, create a Single View Application, and
   disable Use Storyboards but ensure that Use Automatic Reference
   Counting is on.
2. Drag the `GoogleMaps.framework` bundle to the
   Frameworks group of your project. When prompted, select Copy items
   into destination group's folder.
3. Right-click `GoogleMaps.framework` in
   your project, and select Show In Finder.
4. Drag the `GoogleMaps.bundle`
   from the Resources folder to your project. We suggest putting it in
   the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure Copy items into
   destination group's folder is not selected.
5. Select your project from
   the Project Navigator, and choose your application's target. Open
   the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the
   following frameworks:
   AVFoundation.framework
   CoreData.framework
   CoreLocation.framework
   CoreText.framework
   GLKit.framework
   ImageIO.framework
   libc++.dylib
   libicucore.dylib
   libz.dylib
   OpenGLES.framework
   QuartzCore.framework
   SystemConfiguration.framework

Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab.
In the Other Linker Flags section, add `-ObjC`. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All.
Finally, add your API key to your AppDelegate.

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

Add the following to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, replacing     API_KEY with your API key.

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"API_KEY"];
```

Source: [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have already done these steps more than one time but not working for me.

Comment: @regeint: Check the below two checks:  
1. If pods setup is used generally one would get these errors if {project}.Workspace is not used to open the project and {project}.xcodeproject is used.  
2. Check targets > Link with binaries - Whether frameworks are added, If not add frameworks & targets > compile sources - {controllers}.m are seen in this, If not add them manually.

Comment: not working this solution  please unother solution please sir

Answer (score 0):

I often get the same error with other libs. I can't say the exact reason, but it happens when I switch between branches.

The workaround is plain:

- remove workspace generated by cocoapods
- clean project derived data Organiser -> Projects 
  [image: clean derived data]
- run pod install

It always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to play around in pod file's platform setting Vs deployment target in your Target:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

then run `pod update` in terminal.