# Google maps Swift 2 cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift2, cocoapods

I'm triying to implement the google maps SDK in my swift project but when I import GoogleMaps and compile my code I get this errors:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/ligup/Documents/Xcode Projects/Ligup/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps', framework linker option at /Users/ligup/Documents/Xcode Projects/Ligup/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GMSCameraPosition in InformationDetailViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GMSMapView in InformationDetailViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GMSMarker in InformationDetailViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GMSServices in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) tutorial and my Podfile is like this

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

please if you know what I can do to solve this I really appreciate :)

Comment: You probably wan to clean up your project, `rm -rf Pods; Podfile.lock`, and follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31641508/218152

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, in Build Settings in other linking flags I have `-objC`, I change that with $(inherited) like this the first answer of this question [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 while using Google-Maps-iOS-SDK (1.8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248359/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-while-using-google-maps-ios-sdk-1-8-1)